How to train on multiple possible outputs to the same question efficiently in an LLM?
How would you try an LLM with multiple different outputs to the same question efficiently without recalculating the context each time? For example:
System Prompt:
[Some 16k tokens]

Prompt:
My name is

Possible outputs:
My name is Alice
My name is Bob
My name is Charlie
My name is Joe

The traditional method would be to use SFT on each one of these possible outputs individually and making a dataset 4x as large, but that will require recalculating the context of the system prompt 4 times. Is there a more efficient way to train on multiple possible outputs to the same question?
